# Casper set hostname via dhcp

Tags: live-cd, dhcp, pxe

I'm booting sucessfull via pxeboot a live ubuntu remix. I wan't to set the hostname via dhcp because I'm booting several instances of the same image. Right now I'm using a hookline in /etc/dhcp/dhclient-enter-hooks.d/pinhostname  that works quite well.

```
RUN="yes"
if [ "$RUN" = "yes" ]; then
var=`/sbin/ifconfig eth0 | /usr/bin/awk '/inet addr/ {print $2}' | /usr/bin/cut -f2 -d:`
var=`/usr/bin/dig -x $var +short`
var=`echo $var | /usr/bin/awk -F. '{print $1}'`
/bin/hostname $var
fi
```

But the dhcp server comes to late for munin etc and the hostname is not set in time. In the Casper log it shows me it receives the hostname much earlier:

```
IP-Config: eth0 hardware address 08:00:27:86:3e:84 mtu 1500 DHCP RARP
IP-Config: eth0 complete (from 10.1.1.1):
address: 10.1.1.10        broadcast: 10.1.1.255       netmask: 255.255.255.0
gateway: 10.1.1.1         dns0     : 10.1.1.1         dns1   : 0.0.0.0
host   : storage1
domain : domain.com
rootserver: 10.1.1.1 rootpath:
filename  : pxelinux.0
```

How can I set that host name. I think I need to put a script in /scripts before I pack the initrd. There a loads of different scripts where would I put mine?
Thank you for your time

Comment: Are you setting the hostname to the IP address? Or are you using reverse DNS to lookup a name?

Comment: reverse DNS with my script dig -x that works ok. But I want to get rid of my script and use the values casper got. The second "code" block shows what casper sees ages before the init scripts are running. It gets the hostname via pxe boot (dhcp). I want to use that information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a ugly hack that works for me. I unpacked the initrd inserted

```
cat /root/var/log/netboot.config | awk /HOSTNAME/ | cut -f2 -d= | sed 's/.\(.*\)./\1/' > /root/etc/hostname
HOST=`cat /root/var/log/netboot.config | awk /HOSTNAME/ | cut -f2 -d= | sed 's/.\(.*\)./\1/'`
hostname "$HOST"
```

in /**initrd_temp/scripts/casper-bottom/23networking** somewhere after this line:

```
cp /tmp/net-"${DEVICE}".conf /root/var/log/netboot.config
```

Beware this `IS` ugly. This probably should go in 18hostname - but maybe network devices are not up yet.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try dhcpcd5.  I replaced ISC dhclient with dhcpcd5 and it 'just worked'.  Hostname is now set by DHCP answer.